# Kill a process in a telnet connection using a python script

Tags: python, telnet, kill-process, telnetlib

I've established a telnet connection and give commands to start following in real time some data.
Before closing the connection I have to kill the process first.
Manually this can be done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but I don't know how to do it from .py script.
Can anyone have any idea on how to do this? 
Below you can find the code I've used.
Thank you!
Ramona

```
import telnetlib                   


def open_telnet_connection():
    try:
        username = 'username'
        password = 'password'
        ip = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
        reading_timeout = 5

        connection = telnetlib.Telnet(ip)

        console_output = connection.read_until("ENTER USERNAME <", reading_timeout)
        print console_output
        connection.write(username + '\r\n')

        console_output = connection.read_until("ENTER PASSWORD <", reading_timeout)
        connection.write(password + '\r\n')
        print console_output

        connection.write("***My command to follow the process***")
        console_output = connection.read_until("here I can put any text, I use this only to get the output", 600)
        print console_output

        connection.write('***Command instead of Ctrl-C***')  # ***????***
        connection.close()
    except IOError:
        print "connection not established"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    open_telnet_connection()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send `telnetlib.IP` to interrupt the running process.

Change your code to do this:

```py
connection.write(telnetlib.IP)
connection.close()
```